# Making a network request with app in background with Siesta and Swift

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

I'm making an HTTPS request that's initiated from a UNUserNotification action, so it performs with my app running in the background. I suspect that this feature isn't supported by Siesta, in which case I'll make a feature request! But first I want to see if I'm correct about that.

When I set up & make a request in the background using Siesta, no request appears to be made until I open my app, when I get a `URLSessionTask` error code -1003 "HTTP load failed" with message: `URL Session Task Failed: A server with the specified hostname could not be found.`.

This is the exact same behavior I see if I use plain `URLSession` to make requests, without configuring the session for background execution using the boilerplate:

```
let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: String(format: "%f", Date().timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))

config.isDiscretionary = isDiscretionary
config.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
config.sessionSendsLaunchEvents = true
config.timeoutIntervalForResource = backgroundTimeoutInterval

return URLSession(configuration: config,
                  delegate: self,
                  delegateQueue: .main)
```

Is there an out-of-the-box way to get this behavior in Siesta?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Siesta currently does not officially support background requests, though it doesn’t officially rule them out either.

It's not entirely clear what background requests should mean in Siesta. It’s an in-memory cache, so where does the requested data go? However, Siesta’s persistent caches support will soon graduate from “roll your own” to “out of the box,” and at that point background requests become a lot more compelling.

You should be able to pass your Siesta service constructor a `URLSession` configured for background requests as in your example above, and Siesta will happily use it to make requests, same as ever. Less clear is what should happen to those responses when they arrive; you’d be on the hook for persisting the response as necessary.

Comment: The catch is I want to use a background `URLSession` when the app is in the background, and a normal (`default`) `URLSession` when the app is in the foreground. This seems like a `NetworkingProvider` implementation might be called for... however, when I pass it a `URLSession` configured for background requests, I get this error:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: 'Completion handler blocks are not supported in background sessions. Use a delegate instead.'`

Comment: Given that completion handler blocks are used all over the place in Siesta, I wonder if it's even possible to avoid using them without a major rewrite of the Siesta codebase?

Comment: Right, yeah, it sounds like you're in a situation where you need to use a [download task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411482-downloadtask). Siesta does not officially support this. You should in theory be able to write a custom Siesta `NetworkProvider` that supports the download task API. You’d also need to consider how you’ll implement [handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622941-application) (which is true with or without Siesta).